# MMSE estimator with dirac delta prior pdf

Tags: self-study, bayesian, estimation, estimators, dirac-delta

The question is as follows, it's mainly part 3 that I was having problem with.

> A discrete-valued parameter with the prior pdf $$p(x) =
> > \sum_{i=1}^2p_i\delta(x-i)$$ is measured with the additive noise $w ~ N(0, \sigma^2)$. The measurement z is given by: $$z = x + w$$
>
> 1. Find the posterior pdf of the parameter.
> 2. Find the MAP estimate and the associated MSE conditioned on z.
> 3. Find its MMSE estimate and the associated variance.

For part 1, I used Bayes formula and the total probability theorem to get $$p(x|z) = \frac{f(z)}{2\pi\sigma^2}*e^{\frac{(z-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}*\sum_{i=1}^2p_i\delta(x-i)$$
where $f(z) = e^{-\frac{(z-1)^2}{2\sigma^2}} + e^{-\frac{(z-2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

For part 2, I solved $$\frac{d}{dx}[ln(p(x|z)]= 0$$ by considering the dirac delta function as a constant and setting z-x =0, giving $\hat x^{MAP}= z$ and $MSE(\hat x^{MAP})= 0$

However, when it comes to part 3, I know that $\hat x^{MMSE} = E(x|z)$. I also noticed $p(x|z)$ can be divided into three parts, a function of z, a normal distribution of with mean x and variance $\sigma$, and p(x) which involves the dirac delta function. But I'm not sure how to calculate the expected value.

I thought about expanding the summation, and since $\delta(x-i) = 0$ everywhere except for when x = 1 & x = 2, I can just take x = 1 & x = 2 and have $p(x|z)$ as a function of z, which is esentially a constant. But it also seems a little sketchy.

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint and point me in the right direction to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many issues here such as a sign error in what should be $e^{-\frac{(z-x)^2}{\sigma^2}}$  and the implausibility of the MAP being $z$ when that is almost never $1$ or $2$

Comment: Sorry fixed the typo.

Comment: The posterior is incorrect for at least two reasons, you cannot take derivatives when $x\in\{1,2\}$, the posterior mean is the sum of two terms and is not the MMSE when $x\in\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's start with fixing up part 2, then go back to part 1.

Suppose the prior probabilities are equal. The prior is supported only on the set of points $\{1,2\}$, so the posterior will also be supported only on  those points. The MAP estimator must also take values in $\{1,2\}$.  The prior probability is equal on those two points. The loglikelihood for an observation $z$ given $x$ is proportional to $(x-z)^2$, so the posterior probability will be higher on whichever of 1 and 2 is closer to $z$. That gives you the MAP estimator.

To get question 1 (and to handle the non-equal case of question 2), you'd need to quantify how much more likely the closer point is. Bayes' Theorem says $p(x|z)\propto p(x)f(z|x)$, so the probabilities on $\{1,2\}$ are proportional to the $N(0,\sigma^2)$ densities at $z-1$ and $z-2$ respectively.

Now you have the posterior probabilities over the two points you should be able to calculate the posterior mean

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! For question 2, how did you know the prior probability is equal for i = 1 & 2? Why can I assume p1 = p2 in p(x)? For question 1, could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by quantifying how much more likely the closer point is? Is the p(x|z) I had still not the final form? Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, if it's not equal you do need to do part 2 before part 1